# Gliotoxin ingestion and actions needed

Tags: toxicology, mycology

what are the "next day" actions that one has to take, when accidentally ingests contaminated drink/food from Aspergillus or Penicillium or Candida fungus?

Is it feasible to take N-acetyl-L-cysteine supplements? What other measures minimize the damage from the mycotoxins?

What kind of supplements and/or treatments reduce the superoxides produced as effect of the mycotoxins?